# Adding new element in xml

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, xml-attribute

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Day id="Monday">
    <subject name="Software Testing" session="2010" group="Alpha" teacher="Tasawar Khan" classroom="Class Room 1" time="8:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
  <Day id="Tuesday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>

  </Day>
  <Day id="Wednesday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
  <Day id="Thursday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
  <Day id="Friday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>

</Root>
```

**I want to add a subject element in inside  element depending on Id.**
I have written this code for it.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(TeachersXMLPath, FileMode.Open,IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
{
    string session = tb_session.Text.ToString();
    string subject = tb_subject.Text.ToString();
    DateTime? _datetime = val_timer.Value;
    String time = _datetime.Value.Hour + ":" + _datetime.Value.Minute;
    string crdthr = ((ListPickerItem)lst_credithr.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
    string teacher = tb_teacher.Text.ToString();
    string classroom = tb_class.Text.ToString();
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(TeachersXMLPath);
    var newElement = new XElement("subject", new XAttribute("name", subject),
                                          new XAttribute("session", session),
                                          new XAttribute("group", "alpha"),
                                          new XAttribute("teacher", teacher),
                                          new XAttribute("classroom", classroom),
                                          new XAttribute("time", time));

    isoStream.Position = 0;
    loadedData.Root.Add(newElement);
    loadedData.Save(isoStream);
}
```

Now I am facing two problems.

- This code gives no error but when i open the xml file there is no data added at all.
- Second this code even if worked(which is not). It would data inside  . how can i add it inside  with specific id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [`FileMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) to `Create` instead of `Open` because your code loads all existing file to `XDocument` and write the entire `XDocument` back to isolated storage at the end.

To add new `<Subject>` under proper `<Day>` tag, you need to choose the `<Day>` tag first. There are several possible ways to do that, for example :

```
var day = loadedData.Root.Element("Day")
                    .FirstOrDefault(o => (string)o.Attribute("id") == "Thursday");
day.Add(newElement);
loadedData.Save(isoStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edit the FileMode to Create. But still same. There is nothing added in xml file. The problem is, its not even giving any error.